# MS Access - Data Entered in a Form Automatically saves when i close the form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been tasked with making updates to an MS Access Database and its forms.
Each form seems to be linked to a query. If I enter data into a text box on the form and then close the form without pressing the Save Record button a new record is still added to the Database which makes no sense to.

Any insight would be great, I'm a programmer but have little experience working with Access Forms and Databases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft Access binds forms to data by default, and will automatically save data as soon as you either move between records or close the form you're working on. For the average user, this is actually a good thing because it makes it very difficult to lose data, even if you accidentally close the form after making an edit.

If this functionality isn't what you're looking for, I'd suggest removing the binding from the form, that is, set the Record Source property to blank, then manipulate all the data in code using unbound controls. It's a lot more fiddly, but it gives you a lot more control.

The other option would be to use the form's BeforeUpdate event to ask the user if they want to save their changes before allowing them to go through.

If your main concern is accidentally adding new records, set the Allow Additions property to false, and create new records programmatically.

A sample of a BeforeUpdate event procedure (the same code would work for the BeforeInsert event):

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

  Dim intAns As Integer

  intAns = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Record")
  If intAns = vbNo Then Cancel = 1

End Sub
```

If you were to use the above method, and the user clicked "No", they would have to then click the ESC key to undo the changes they had entered. Otherwise it would keep showing the dialogue when they moved off the record.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much that is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I might use the BeforeUpdate method you mentioned.  Thanks again!

Comment: If I were to use the BeforeUpdate Flag what would be the best method to use that event to then add new data to the DB?

Comment: I've added a sample of a BeforeUpdate event procedure that might help. You can use the same code for a BeforeInsert event procedure, which would ask the user before adding a new record. In both cases, if the user selects "No", they won't be able to move off the record until they undo their changes using hte ESC key.

The other thing you might consider for adding new records is to temporarily change the DataEntry property of the form to true, using a command button. Doing it right is a little more complicated though.

Comment: Awesome thanks, that pretty much exactly what my code looks like. I added in the 'Undo' property on the No condition which basically cancels commiting the query.  Thanks again.